# added multiple actions @selector

Tags: iphone

Have a playpause button on the mainviewcontroller. This button basically is toggling between play and pause buttons which is working fine. Now i added another action to playpause button. When i hit the play button it is not showing pageview at the sametime while toggling between play and pause.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "ModalViewController.h"
#import "PageOneViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)modalViewAction:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIBarButtonSystemItem currentSystemItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ModalViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

@end



@synthesize pageViewController = _pageViewController;


UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pageViewControllerAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playpauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *playpause = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playpauseButton];

-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{
    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer pause];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer play];
    }    
}

- (void)pageViewControllerAction:(id)sender
{
    CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
    pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 40.0, 40.0);

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;

    // Configure the page view controller 
    UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [[[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil]autorelease];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pageViewController]; 

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
}
```

Tried Exception breakpoint it is showing exception breakpoint at

`[audioPlayer play];`

also tried adding breakpoint at

`-(void)pageViewControllerAction:`

it is not executing that.

Any ideas what is going on. What i m doing wrong.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is not executing the

```
(void)pageViewControllerAction:(id)sender
```

because you have exception in the previous method? Where is this **audioPlayer** defined and initialized? That might be the issue here.

Secondly, why do you need two actions. Just have one and call the other function from inside that.

example:

```
UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  //  [playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pageViewControllerAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playpauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);



-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{
if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer pause];
} else {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
}    


[self pageViewControllerAction]; // Here is the call to the other function
}
```

**Edit:**
Lastly make sure you have the function defined in your .h file as follows:

```
- (void) pageViewControllerAction;
```

Aside:
I did not get your image setting logic. Seems like a bug in that logic. You also need to state the **UIControlStateSelected** after the button is hit. You are only setting the **UIControlStateNormal**

Comment: audioplayer is defined in the viewdidload

Comment: when i type [self pageViewControllerAction]; getting warning in yellow that instance method pageViewControllerAction not found

Comment: Ahh that tells you something right? post your .h file. You have not added that function in the .h file. See edited response

Comment: added that function still not working. Getting yellow warning in m file that incomplete implementation after i added function

Comment: That's because you are hitting the other exception. Resolve that. You had multiple code issues ...

Comment: what exception u r talking about

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the sender as an argument for the selector:

```
- (void)pageViewControllerAction:(id)sender
    { ... }
```

Comment: Have you defined them on your header file?